# Have ever seen or will ever see

Tags: grammar

Please look at the following

This is the best performance ***I have ever seen***. This means I have never seen a performance which was better than this, so this is the best. Am I right?

Similarly, when we say

This is the best performance ***I ever saw***. I think this means the same as above. Am I right? If not, then please tell me what the difference is

But, when we say

This is the best performance ***I will ever see***. This sentence confuses me really.I don't understand what this means. Can anyone please explain to me what it means?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer

> This is the best performance I have ever seen.

over

> This is the best performance I ever saw.

They mean the same thing (namely, that the person saying it witnessed the best performance thus far in their life) unless context implies otherwise.

---

> This is the best performance I will ever see.

The sentence means they will never see a better performance; it's impossible for another performance taking place in the future to be better than this one.

Answer (score 0):

> This is the best performance I have ever seen.

Uses a verb tense `have seen` which indicates it is the best performance in the past or present.

> This is the best performance I ever saw.

Uses a verb tense `saw` which indicates it is the best performance in the past, but the performance is over.  This means that the better wording (better agreement in time) would be

> This was the best performance I ever saw.

Because now the verb tenses are similar.  The performance `was` is in the past, and the sight of it `saw` was in the past.  Both verbs match (agree) about the time of the performance.

> This is the best performance I will ever see.

Is a person stating something about the future.  They believe they will never see a better performance.  In their mind, at this time, it is not possible for a performance to be better.